# Should I create separate provider for service in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have custom service in Laravel:

```
<?php
namespace App\Library\Services;

class RegisterCustomerService
{
    public function do()
    {
        return 'Output from DemoOne';
    }

}
```

In which cases I should create provider for this service, when not?

Could I use `RegisterCustomerService` as composition in specific class like:

```
$c = new RegisterCustomerService();
```

Or am i obligated to create Provider?

Comment: Service providers are only necessary if the service needs custom configuration. You can typehint any class in the constructor and Laravel will try to resolve it to an instance.

Comment: That comment should be an answer @MaartenDev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service providers are only necessary if the service needs custom configuration. You can typehint any class in the constructor and Laravel will try to resolve it to an instance.

An example service provider that configures a service with a config value is shown below:

```php
class MyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
   public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(MyCustomService::class, function ($app) {
            return new MyCustomService(config('api_token'));
        });
    }
}
```

usage:

```php
class ProjectController {
  // Receives the service configured by the service provider above.
  public function __construct(MyCustomService $service){
    $this->service = $service;
  }
}
```

More details about service providers: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/providers